# Openstreetmaps + OpenLayers images to custom maps

Tags: maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have an idea for a project I want to do, but I am not sure how to get started. I am looking to create a map of the inside of a building using a simple image editor. The inside of the building will contain certain points which I would like to reference later on.

For example, I want to be able to use something like openstreetmap + Openlayers, and then search for, let's say, room A, and have openstreetmap handle where that point is on the map.

I started off with this tutorial:
http://macwright.org/2012/08/13/images-as-maps.html

However, I am not sure if I am moving into the right direction. Does anyone out there have any experience doing something like this? I am not sure if the stack I have in mind is the right way to go.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want your rooms to be seen as a dot in the map or as a polygon with its real expanses?

Comment: ideally the rooms should have been mapped out in the editor. Unless I can use Openlayers to fill in the room area. I just want to be able to  "find" the rooms later on.

Comment: do you have allready made drawings of the rooms or are you going to do that in your editor?

Comment: I will be doing that as soon as I figure out what the best approach is to take.

Comment: Try the answer I have post in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455477/vector-tiles-on-top-of-raster-tiles-is-not-getting-displayed-in-openlayers/46538341#46538341